# MyBatis - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection already contains value

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I use Spring and MyBatis for my application. I had no exception until I changed package to a class I use as ResultType.
Since then, I receive the following error while starting my application:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection already contains value for app2Check.core.dao.ThemeSentimentDAO.getSplitMatchingThemes
at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration$StrictMap.put(Configuration.java:782)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration$StrictMap.put(Configuration.java:754)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.addMappedStatement(Configuration.java:578)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.MapperBuilderAssistant.addMappedStatement(MapperBuilderAssistant.java:288)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLStatementBuilder.parseStatementNode(XMLStatementBuilder.java:107)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.buildStatementFromContext(XMLMapperBuilder.java:135)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.buildStatementFromContext(XMLMapperBuilder.java:128)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.configurationElement(XMLMapperBuilder.java:118)
... 67 more
```

Here is my xml mapper (I had to censore the queries, but they were not changed):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="app2Check.core.dao.ThemeSentimentDAO">
<select id="getSplitMatchingThemes" resultType="xyz.objects.sentences.SplitSent"><!-- Previously resultType="xyz.sentences.SplitSent" -->
    SELECT TOP (#{numSplitPerPage})
        ...
        <if  test = "redo == false">
            ...
        </if>
    WHERE (
            <foreach collection="themes" item="t" index="index" separator=" OR ">
                (
                    ..
                )
            </foreach>
        )

</select>

<select id="getThemes" resultType="xyz.objects.Theme">
...
</select>

<select id="countSplitMatchingTheme"  resultType="xyz.utils.SplitCount">
    ...
</select>

</mapper>
```

This is my mapper interface:

```
public interface ThemeSentimentDAO {

    public List<Theme> getThemes(@Param("appId") String appId);

    public List<SplitFeedback> getSplitMatchingThemes(
            @Param("appId") String appId, 
            @Param("customerCare") String customerCare,
            @Param("redo") boolean redo,
            @Param("analysisDate") Timestamp analysisDate,
            @Param("themes") List<Theme> themes,
            @Param("numSplitPerPage") int numSplitPerPage
            );

    public SplitCount countSplitMatchingTheme(
            @Param("appId") String appId, 
            @Param("customerCare") String customerCare,
            @Param("redo") boolean redo,
            @Param("themes") List<Theme> themes
            );
    }
```

Comment: Is that the full stack trace? I'm not sure what is going on, but you seem to be using very old version of MyBatis (3.2.x?). You should try upgrading to 3.5.4 if that's possible. Is the error gone if you move the class back to the original package `xyz.sentences.SplitSent`?

Comment: This is the last part of the stack trace, there were similar exception before this. Yes, I use an old version of myBatis because it was the latest version when the project started and we had never had this problem before

Comment: The problem didn't solved moving the class back to the original package. At th moment I solved moving queries from xml to annotation in the interface